# How to create a login form with a shaky effect without JS or JQ?

Tags: html, forms, css

Is this possible? I want to give the user feedback that one of the fields is not (correctly) filled in. I want the input box to shake. Is this possible with CSS animation only and how? Because the required option does not work in the StackOverflow editor: here's a link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWpyMz

```css
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="JohnSnow@gmail.com" id="email" required />
        <li>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="*********" id="password" required/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button>Login</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

enter code here

Comment: If this event (the shake) is happening on validation, then no, you can't trigger it without js. There is no other way for the input to know that something is wrong if you don't tell it.

Comment: just call your animation from a css rule: example: `input:focus{
  animation: shake 1s ;
}`

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/OWpRgY

the snippet below don't work properly but the link above works fine

```css
input:focus {
  animation: 0.4s shake;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <ul>
       <li>
       <label for="email">email</label>
       <input type="email" placeholder="JohnSnow@gmail.com" id="email" required />
       <li>
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="*********" id="password" required/>
       </li>
       </ul>     
       <button >Login</button> 
  </fieldset>
</form>
```